# Install gcc 7.2 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, gcc, cuda

[NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 9.2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.htmlallation-guide-linux/index.html) currently supports only Gcc 7.2.0 for Ubuntu 17.10.

However, Ubuntu 18.04 comes with default gcc 7.3.0.

How can I downgrade gcc 7.3 to 7.2, or make CUDA 9.2 work with gcc 7.3 in Ubuntu 18.04?